# NSBatchDeleteRequest deletes all child entities

Tags: swift, core-data, nsbatchdeleterequest

My CoreData model got two child entities "CarA" and "CarB" with the same abstract parent entity "Car".

I'm trying to delete all CarA objects using

```
    func deleteObjects(entityName: String) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        do {
            try context.execute(deleteRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Executing `deleteObjects("CarA")` results in deleting not only all CarA objects, but also all CarB objects as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me like a bug.  If you enable SQLDebug, you can see from the console output that the entire parent entity is deleted:

```
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZABSTRACT
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
```

(my parent entity is named "Abstract").  But I notice that if you add a predicate, CoreData remembers to qualify the underlying fetch to restrict it to the correct child entity.  So a workaround is to add a predicate that is always true:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(value:true)
```

and the resulting console output is:

```
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZABSTRACT WHERE Z_PK IN (SELECT t0.Z_PK FROM ZABSTRACT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_ENT = ? )
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
```

It seems CoreData even optimises out the true predicate, leaving only the WHERE clause to limit the delete to the correct entity.